# Low F1-Score due to Imbalanced Dataset even after resampling

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, scikit-learn

I am performing a Binary Classification over an **imbalanced dataset**:
0: 16,263
1: 214

I have used multiple oversampling, undersampling, and combination techniques, below are the results that I have obtained:
I obtained this plots thanks to this piece of code:

```
def plot_resampling(X, y, sampler, ax, title=None):
    X_res, y_res = sampler.fit_resample(X, y)
    ax.scatter(X_res[:, 0], X_res[:, 1], c=y_res, alpha=0.8, edgecolor="k")
    if title is None:
        title = f"Resampling with {sampler.__class__.__name__}"
    ax.set_title(title)
    sns.despine(ax=ax, offset=10)
```

***Clarification: The X and y are the X_train and y_train and I used it to show the distribution of my data points before and after the resampling.***

[image: Comparison Initial Dataset and multiple oversampling techniques]

**For the RandomUnderSampler, the first one is without replacement and the second one is with replacement=True**
[image: Comparison Initial Dataset and multiple oversampling techniques]

[image: Use of Combination techniques]

You need to know also that I have **multiple outliers in my dataset**, and hence, multiple columns are skewed, so I chose to use models that are not sensitive to skewness like:

- SVC
- Naive Bayes Classifier
- Ensemble XGboost
- KNN

For now, the best result that I have obtained is with **SVC(kernel = "rbf")** and using the **SMOTE technique**(Of course the sampling is only performed on the training dataset since the test one should represent the real population):

- **Test Accuracy: 0.75**
- **Training Accuracy: 0.88**

But the classification report is not good, the **f1-score is 0.51**, there is a **real issue with the 1 class** even after the resampling!! as you can see below:
[image]
Here is also the Confusion Matrix:
[image]
Can you please help me improve the f1 score, what is your analysis of the situation, and what are your suggestions?

Comment: What are the axes in your plots?

Comment: @BenReiniger I have edited the post to show you how I obtained this plots, the axes are: 
X_res[:, 0]   and X_res[:, 1]